# Responsive multiple pieCharts in ReactHighcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive

I´m using ReactHighcharts for visualize my series in piecharts.

My Question is:
How to visualize multiple piecharts in a responsive way which are get their data dynamically. I can´t change the "center" piecharts prop manually, so I have iterate through the series with a for loop and set the center properties automatically.

```js
const config = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Group Name'
    },
    series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    name: 'bar',
    center: ["20%", "50%"]//Horizontal and vertical position
  }, {
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    name: 'bar',
    center: ["40%", "50%"]//Horizontal and vertical position
  }, {
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    name: 'bar',
    center: ["60%", "50%"]//Horizontal and vertical position
  }, {
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    name: 'bar',
    center: ["80%", "50%"]//Horizontal and vertical position
  }],
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }                
        }            
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.7/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found a solution that show me the pieCharts in a responsive way.
It´s also working with ReactHighcharts. The only thing that you have to change is:

From: Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.getCenter

To: ReactHighcharts.Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.getCenter

I hope I could help some other people with the same issue.

Here is the problem solving code snipping:

```js
Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.getCenter = function () {
 var allPies = this.chart.series.filter(function (s) {
            return s.type === 'pie';
        }),
        count = allPies.length,
        index = allPies.indexOf(this),
        plotWidth = this.chart.plotWidth,
        plotHeight = this.chart.plotHeight,
        smallestSize = Math.min(plotWidth / count, plotHeight);

 return [(plotWidth / count) * (index + 0.5) , plotHeight / 2, smallestSize, 0] 
};

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Group Name'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: 'bar'
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: 'bar'
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: 'bar'
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }                
        }            
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.7/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```